# Trocar option de select de acordo com o option selecionado em outro select

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

O Problema: Em uma página tenho dois select, um que seleciona a equipe e outro os membros da equipe, o primeiro(da equipe) eu preencho os `option` com php(por consulta no banco de dados), assim ele vai listar todas equipes que tenho registradas no banco de dados. Quero que ao trocar a equipe nesse `select`, para  que ele carregue no `select` todos os membros dessa equipe (também gravados no banco de dados).

Pensei em fazer com `Jquery` e `Ajax`, no change de `select.equipe` ele realizar requisiçao em uma página php, que faz  a busca de membros relacionados ao id  da equipe selecionada. Mas estou com problema na hora de pegar o retorno do php, pois serao mais de um membro.

Tentei montar em  php uma `string` em html com os options e depois dar um `append`  dessa string no `select.membros`, mas sem resultados.

Tentei também  com  `.html` no lugar de `.append`. Pesquisei em vários locais e só encontrei como colocar `option` um por um, e não resolve meu caso pois tenho que colocar vários ao mesmo tempo, e os resultados da consulta são montados em options com valores correspondente ao id do membro e `content` com  o nome do membro.

Como faço para adicionar vários option no `select.membros` e apagar os mesmo no `.change` do `select.equipe`? Ou se tiver um método melhor  de se fazer isso (trocar os option de select.membros de acordo com o change do select.equipe) como faço?

Desculpem a má  formatação, é urgente e estou pelo celular.

Comment: Por que não retornar um JSON pelo PHP? Aí é só iterar a lista/array e adicionar cada elemento dela como membro da equipe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ivcs, já que você quer carregar o segundo select de forma dinamica, é interresante que a chamada asyncrona (AJAX) retorne um JSON.

infelizmente não sou um conhecedor de PHP, mas realizando uma breve consulta no Google, obtive este exemplo:

```
$json_str = json_encode($membros);
echo "$json_str";
```

agora supondo que o o seu objeto `$membros` é um `Array` de objetos cujo a classe possuem as propriedades `Id` e `Nome`, deste caso teremos uma saida semelhante a seguinte:

```
[
  { "Id": 1, "Nome": "João" },
  { "Id": 3, "Nome": "Pedro" },
  { "Id": 5, "Nome": "Maria" },
  { "Id": 7, "Nome": "Ana" },
  { "Id": 11, "Nome": "Severino" }
];
```

então agora precisamos apenas realizar a chamada AJAX:

```js
var json = document.getElementById("tmplJson").innerHTML;
var blob = new Blob([json], { type: 'application/json' });
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

var membros = document.getElementById("membros");
var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
httpRequest.responseType = "json"
httpRequest.open("GET", url, true);
httpRequest.addEventListener("readystatechange", function (event) {
  if (httpRequest.readyState == 4) {
    if (httpRequest.status == 200) {
      membros.innerHTML = "";
      httpRequest.response.forEach(function (membro, indice) {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = membro.Id;
        option.textContent = membro.Nome;
        membros.appendChild(option);
      });
    } else {
    
    }
  }
});

httpRequest.send();
```

```html
<template id="tmplJson">
  [
    { "Id": 1, "Nome": "João" },
    { "Id": 3, "Nome": "Pedro" },
    { "Id": 5, "Nome": "Maria" },
    { "Id": 7, "Nome": "Ana" },
    { "Id": 11, "Nome": "Severino" }
  ]
</template>

<select id="membros">
</select>
```